# using if( num & 2) as a conditional in c++?

Tags: c++, c

I am pondering over something I have never come across.. maybe there is a reason.  Hopefully someone can quickly identify the pattern!

The value of ***test*** checks for odd numbers, or even if changed to ***2***:

```
int num = 1;
int test = 1;
while (num <= 255) {
    if (num & test) {
        cout << num << " num & 2 =" << (num & 2) << endl;
    }
    num++;
}
```

Question 1: how can you describe the mathematical operation ***num & test***

Question 2: what happens if ***test*** is equal to ***3,4, or 5***?

Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: That's a normal [bitwise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), and follows all the rules of [bitwise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). I really miss the "good old days" when one had to learn bitwise arithmetic to be a good programmer, not get of my lawn! ;)

Comment: google "bitwise AND"

Comment: if `num & test` equals 0, the if statement won't be executed. Just remember the `&` is bitwise

Comment: Thank you for the timely response!

Comment: You have `test = 1` but in the output hard-coded `2` which has caused you perhaps some confusion: `num & 2` will *not* test for even numbers, and `num & 1` tests for even *not* odd.  There is an implicit conversion to boolean that is best made explicit; so for odd: `(num & 1) != 0` and even `(num & 1) == 0`.  For example `3&2 == 2` and `4&2 == 0`, so clearly it is not a valid test for even.

Comment: @ChrisD Since when `4 & 1` is true?

Comment: @qrdl That's never true. I reread OPs post. I thought he/she meant if the operation num & test evaluated to 3, 4, or 5. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Answer 1: The operation is bitwise AND

```
Example num = 10, test = 1
10 = 1010b, 1 = 0001b 
num & test = 0000b
```

`if(num & test)` is equivalent to `if(bool(num & test)) bool(10 & 1) == bool(0) == false`

Answer 2:

> > the value test checks for odd numbers

only when test = 1, because all odd numbers have 1b in lowest bit

```
1 = 0001b
2 = 0010b
3 = 0011b
4 = 0100b
etc.

Example num = 10, test = 3
10 = 1010b, 3 = 0011b
num & test = 10 & 3 = 1010b & 0011b = 0010b = 2
```